# Javascript - Stop Running stopInterval After x Times

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I have a web app that I want to run a setInterval function 2 times and then terminate.  My code is listed below:

```js
var numCalls = 0
       setInterval(function(){
           document.forms[0].submit();
           if (numCalls >2){
               window.clearInterval();
                }
       }, 10000);
```

The setInterval function keeps running - any help with getting this code to run with its intended purpose is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you submitting a form multiple times? Also, you aren't incrementing ``numCalls`` in the code there.

Comment: you want to use setTimeout, then, not setInterval. setInterval schedules an infinitely repeating set of calls. setTimeout runs only once, so you can simply check to see if it's fired X times, if not, increment your counter and call it anew. Read ye some http://fitzgeraldnick.com/weblog/35/

Comment: 1. you did not modify numCalls; 2. you need feed the return value from setInterval to clearInterval.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans you can cancel ``setInterval`` if you've assigned the return value of it to a variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
var myTimer = setInterval(....
   ...
   clearInterval(myTimer);
   ...
}, 10000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var numCalls = 0
       var interval = setInterval(function(){
           document.forms[0].submit();
           numCalls++;
           if (numCalls >2){
               window.clearInterval(interval);
                }
       }, 10000);
```

Comment: That's assuming ``document.forms[0].submit();`` doesn't throw an error, lol

Comment: Agreed.  Trying not to sweat the small stuff :)

Comment: In my opinion, it's more important to address the issue of whether he should be asking this at all before answering it.

Comment: We all start somewhere.  What's obvious to you or me might not be so obvious to someone starting out, and SO is for programming Questions and Answers.  So why we all debate whether to answer the question, some poor guy is tearing his hair out trying to learn.  Took me longer to type this than answer the question :).  I suppose whether it's a good question or not probably depends on if you're the guy tearing your hair out.

Comment: "You forgot the semicolon."

Comment: Joe, I appreciate your understanding.  Guys, I understand that there were some serious fundamental mistakes that I made.  However, I'm trying to learn and solve a problem at the same time.  I hope that you a little less harsh with others in the future.  It's really not called for.